# getting "Handshake response not received." after closing websocket

Tags: java, java-websocket, tyrus

I'm using tyrus websocket client (1.11) to connect to a websocket.

```
compile 'org.glassfish.tyrus:tyrus-client:1.+'
compile 'org.glassfish.tyrus:tyrus-container-grizzly-client:1.+'
```

I'm running a local `wscat` server (`wscat --listen`) to test my connection.

What my client does is that it connects to the websocket, sends a text string followed by a binary load (0xb5,0xb2,0xb1,0xb0,0xb1,0xb2,0xc6), followed by another string and then disconnects.

This is what the server sees (and is exactly what I expect):

```
listening on port 8666 (press CTRL+C to quit)
client connected
< Ohai, Server!
< �������
< Bye, Server!
disconnected
```

***Note***: The entity doing the connection, the `Monkey` class extends `Thread` and runs asynchronously so some log lines may be out of order.

Things aren't as peachy on the client side, though. While the logs agree that a connection was made, the three chunks were sent, and the connection was closed, it also gives me a stacktrace that *connection failed because no handshake response was received* (See the full log [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12275940/)):

```
...
[org.glassfish.tyrus.client.TyrusClientEngine] FINE: > Session af609b3f-2978-453f-9758-10351d5ed2af [43 ms]: Sending handshake request:
> GET ws://127.0.0.1:8666
> Connection: Upgrade
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8666
> Origin: 127.0.0.1:8666
> Sec-WebSocket-Key: pGNihDxLIbQqcxvMTBERSQ==
> Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: binary
> Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
> Upgrade: websocket

[org.glassfish.tyrus.client.TyrusClientEngine] FINE: < Session af609b3f-2978-453f-9758-10351d5ed2af [324 ms]: Received handshake response: 
< 101
< connection: Upgrade
< sec-websocket-accept: EZjq5dEOzWz2q46tKtNlVD8K+mk=
< sec-websocket-protocol: binary
< upgrade: websocket
...
[MONKEY_0] FINER: Session 'af609b3f-2978-453f-9758-10351d5ed2af' opened
[RUNNER] INFO: MONKEY_0 connected
[MONKEY_0] FINER: Sending messages...
[MONKEY_0] FINER: Saying Hi...
[org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusRemoteEndpoint] FINEST: > Session af609b3f-2978-453f-9758-10351d5ed2af [335 ms]: Sending text message: Ohai, Server!
...
[MONKEY_0] FINER: Said Hi. Now Sending binary data...
[org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusRemoteEndpoint] FINEST: > Session af609b3f-2978-453f-9758-10351d5ed2af [342 ms]: Sending binary message
[MONKEY_0] FINER: Binary sent. Saying Bye...
[org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusRemoteEndpoint] FINEST: > Session af609b3f-2978-453f-9758-10351d5ed2af [344 ms]: Sending text message: Bye, Server!
[MONKEY_0] FINER: Messages sent.
[MONKEY_0] INFO: Closing socket.
[org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusRemoteEndpoint] FINE: Close public void close(CloseReason cr): CloseReason[1000,Bye]
...
[MONKEY_0] FINER: Session 'af609b3f-2978-453f-9758-10351d5ed2af' closed (Bye)
[RUNNER] INFO: MONKEY_0 disconnected
[MONKEY_0] SEVERE: Unable to connect to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8666'
javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Handshake response not received.
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3$1.run(ClientManager.java:691)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3.run(ClientManager.java:712)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(ClientManager.java:866)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:511)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:373)
    at com.redacted.webmonkey.monkey.Monkey.connect(Monkey.java:90)
    at com.redacted.webmonkey.monkey.Monkey.run(Monkey.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1039)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1328)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:277)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3$1.run(ClientManager.java:666)
    ... 9 more
...
[RUNNER] SEVERE: 'MONKEY_0' failed. Error: Cannot connect
...
```

Why is there an apparent second attempt to connect?
What is going on here?

I threw in a few timestamps to see what's actually going on:

```
Session s = null;
try {
    LOG.d("(%d) attempting to connect", System.currentTimeMillis());
    WebSocketContainer wsc = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
    s = wsc.connectToServer(this, uri);
    LOG.d("(%d) Connected", System.currentTimeMillis());
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOG.e("(%d) Unable to connect to '%s'", System.currentTimeMillis(), uri);
    e.printStackTrace();
}

LOG.d("(%d) Session id : %s", System.currentTimeMillis(), s == null ? null : s.getId());
return s != null;
```

What I actually get suggests that I cannot connect (Yet I did and sent those messages, didn't I?)

```
[MONKEY_0] FINER: (1441396510763) attempting to connect
[MONKEY_0] FINER: (1441396511068) Session '4c0b1f6e-de7e-471d-a801-f807895c4a0b' opened
[MONKEY_0] FINER: (1441396511079) Session '4c0b1f6e-de7e-471d-a801-f807895c4a0b' closed (Bye)
[MONKEY_0] SEVERE: (1441396511080) Unable to connect to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8666'
[MONKEY_0] FINER: (1441396511081) Session id : null
```

It looks like the connect call is blocked while I transact with the ws. Does it assume there was an error because the connection is closed at the end of the `onOpen` callback?

Comment: can you please explicitly set dependency version to 1.11? It seems you might be using something older..

Comment: The version number is actually from what is displayed in the IDE, but I'll try an explicit version too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it seems that closing the session during the `onOpen` callback *is indeed the reason* why the `WebsocketContainer` gets confused and thinks the connection failed.
Just for testing, I was sending the messages using the `getBasicRemote()` (synchronous) and then closing the socket after all were done.
I switched to using `getAsyncRemote()` and closing after all messages were sent and now the wsc correctly reports success in connection.

I wonder if it's a good idea to block on the callback?

Answer (score 0):

Do not call `Thread.sleep()` in `onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig endpointConfig)`. Use your own thread to send message, `ClientManager.connect` return Session object, use this object to send messages.